# Firebase Firestore - How much does a write operation with field transforms (eg. increments) cost?

Tags: firebase, google-cloud-firestore

[Transactions and batched writes](https://cloud.google.com/firestore/docs/manage-data/transactions#batched-writes) guide points out that:

> Within a write operation, field transforms like `serverTimestamp`, `arrayUnion`, and `increment` each count as an additional operation.

So, if a **write** on a single document costs `1 w`, how much does a **write** operation with 10 `increment`s (on different fields of the same document) cost? `2 w` or `11 w`?

Comment: I don't necessarily take that documentation to be a statement about billing.  It sounds like it's talking about how to compute the maximum number of "operations" allowed for a single batch, up to 500 per batch. If you are unclear, please contact Firebase support directly: https://support.google.com/firebase/contact/support